# Storing an arraylist for retrieval in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, arraylist

I'm currently working on an Android application that is going to be somewhat like a student planner. My backend is all java and I am currently stuck because i am storing the objects that i create from my backend to arraylist. Being java, these objects dissapear as soon as the programs terminate. Whats the easiest way that i can store my java objects for retrieval the next time i boot my application? Any help is much appreciated! Im developing on 2.3 and eclipse(juno).

Answer (score 2):

One of the data storage options [listed in the Android developer tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) will be the easiest thing to do. Which is the best fit will depend on how much data you're storing and how you need to access it. As the page says, the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) class is best for a handful of items; for larger data sets, you could use Java serialization or some other way to [write them to a file](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) on the phone's storage; and if your data are large and/or you need structured access to them, [an SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store your data. The `SharedPreferences` lets you persist key-value pairs of primitive data types in you application. You can't store an entire `ArrayList` with a single key, but you can iterate over the array and systematically generate a key for each value in the list. I usually do something like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Data> list; //We'll persist this array

    /* snip */

    //These strings can be anything - you just need something you can use to systematically generate distinct keys
    public static final String LIST_KEY = "SomeActivity_List";
    public static final String LIST_LENGTH_KEY = "SomeActivity_ListLength";

    /**
     * How this method works: It starts by getting a SharedPreferences object,
     * which offers an API for persisting data. It then systematically generates
     * Strings like "SomeActivity_List1", "SomeActivity_List2", "SomeActivity_List3",
     * and so on to use as keys fot the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. elements in the list. Then
     * it Data.saveData(), a method defined below in the Data class, in order to give
     * each Data object in the ArrayList an opportunity to persist its primitive
     * members in the SharedPreferences.
     *
     * SomeActivity.restoreList() works similarly.
     */
    public void saveList() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(); //This method is part of the Activity class
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.getEditor();

        //Save the length of the list so that when we restore it, we know how many
        //Data objects to recreate.
        editor.putInt(LIST_LENGTH_KEY, list.size());
        editor.commit();

        //This for loop is important - note how we concatenate i to each of the keys to give each element in list a distinct key
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            String identifier = LIST_KEY + Integer.toString(i); //generate distinct keys
            list.get(i).saveData(identifier, prefs);
        }
    }

    public void restoreList() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences();

        int length = prefs.getInt(LIST_LENGTH_KEY);

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            String identifier = LIST_KEY + Integer.toString(i); //re-generate distinct keys
            Data data = new Data();
            data.restoreData(identifier, prefs);
            list.addLast(data);
        }
    }

    public static class Data {
        private int i;
        private double j;
        private String s;

        public static final String I_KEY = "Data_I"
        public static final String J_KEY = "Data_J" //strings can really be whatever, as long as they're distinct.
        public static final String S_KEY = "Data_K"

        /**
         * How this method works: The SomeActivity.saveList() method generates a
         * unique String ("identifier") for each of the Data objects it contains.
         * This method uses that distinct string and makes some more distinct keys
         * to store each of Data's primitive members.
         *
         * restoreData() works similarly when it rebuilds Data objects
         */
        public saveData(String identifier, SharedPreferences prefs) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.getEditor();
            editor.putInt(I_KEY + identifier, i);
            editor.putDouble(J_KEY + identifier, j);
            editor.putString(S_KEY + identifier, s);
            editor.commit();
        }

        public restoreData(String identifier, SharedPreferences prefs) {
            i = prefs.getInt(I_KEY + identifier);
            j = prefs.getDouble(J_KEY + identifier);
            s = prefs.getString(S_KEY + identifier);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach work recursively. If Data had an ArrayList as one of its fields, for example, it could systematically store all of the values in that list in SharedPreferences as well.

FYI: One of the implications of using SharedPreferences is that if the user uninstalls your app or clears the app data, the stored list will be deleted. Depending on the nature of your data, you may or may not want this behavior.